# Three pandas columns to nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns

```
   c1   c2  c3
0  A   C    1
1  A   D    2
2  B   E    3
3  B   E    4
```

I would like to turn it into a nested dictionary, so something like `{'A': {'C': [1], 'D': [2]}, 'B': {'E': [3,4]}`

How should I do this? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `.to_dict()`?

Answer (score 3):

Try with `groupby` and `to_dict`:

```
>>> df.groupby('c1').apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(zip(x['c2'], x['c3'])).groupby(0)[1].apply(list).to_dict()).to_dict()
{'A': {'C': [1], 'D': [2]}, 'B': {'E': [3, 4]}}
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use a combination of dictionary comprehension, [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) and [`Series.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
output = {
    c1: g_df.groupby('c2')['c3'].agg(list).to_dict()
    for c1, g_df in df.groupby('c1')
}
```

`output`:

```
{'A': {'C': [1], 'D': [2]}, 'B': {'E': [3, 4]}}
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'c1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    'c2': ['C', 'D', 'E', 'E'],
    'c3': [1, 2, 3, 4]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way which you can try:

```
out=(df.groupby(['c1','c2']).agg(list).unstack(0).droplevel(0,1)
       .agg(lambda x:dict(x.dropna())).to_dict())
```

output:

```
{'A': {'C': [1], 'D': [2]}, 'B': {'E': [3, 4]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us try

```
s = df.groupby(['c1','c2'])['c3'].agg(list)
d = {l: s.xs(l).to_dict() for l in s.index.levels[0]}
d
Out[31]: {'A': {'C': [1], 'D': [2]}, 'B': {'E': [3, 4]}}
```